# embed tomcat to grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails-2.2

I finished an application built with Grails , i want the to embed the tomcat server into my application so all the end user has to do is to run .exe or batch file to run the application without installing tomcat or any web server, is that applicable , if yes how to approach this ?

Thanks
Sherif

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Grails Standalone plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/standalone) created by Burt Beckwith.The Standalone plugin builds a runnable JAR file with an embedded war built from your application and an embedded Tomcat 7 or Jetty 7 instance. This allows you to build a single archive that can be run on any computer with Java 5 or higher by running java -jar standalone.jar.

Comment: any other tools beside the above tool ?

Comment: there is the jetty standalone plugin - http://grails.org/plugin/jetty-standalone. Another option is to embed Tomcat or Jetty by yourself

Comment: is there any tutorials for embedding tomcat in grails application ?

Comment: Take a look at the Standalone plugin sources - https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-standalone